# How to prevent Weights & Biases from saving unnecessary parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, wandb

I am using Weights & Biases ([link](https://wandb.ai/)) to manage hyperparameter optimization and log the results. I am training using Keras with a Tensorflow backend, and I am using the out-of-the-box logging functionality of Weights & Biases, in which I run

```
wandb.init(project='project_name', entity='username', config=config)
```

and then add a `WandbCallback()` to the callbacks of `classifier.fit()`. By default, Weights & Biases appears to save the model parameters (i.e., the model's weights and biases) and store them in the cloud. This eats up my account's storage quota, and it is unnecessary --- I only care about tracking the model loss/accuracy as a function of the hyperparameters.

Is it possible for me to train a model and log the loss and accuracy using Weights & Biases, but not store the model parameters in the cloud? How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to not save the trained model weights during hyperparam optimization you do something like this:

```
classifier.fit(..., callbacks=[WandbCallback(.., save_model=False)]
```

This will only track the metrics (train/validation loss/acc, etc.).